# How to compute returns from cumulative returns in Python?

Tags: programming, numerical-methods, asset-returns

If X is a $T\times N$ pandas DataFrame of multivariate asset returns, the cumulative returns can be computed in python as

> (1 + X).cumprod() - 1

How can I reverse this operation so that I go backwards from cumulative returns to the original returns matrix X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataFrame `df` with a few random returns that I made up:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'rets': (.5, .5, .4, .3)})
```

Add `cum_rets` column:

```
df['cum_rets'] = (1 + df['rets']).cumprod() - 1
```

Add `inv_cum_rets` colum:

```
df['inv_cum_rets'] = ((1 + df['cum_rets']) / (1 + df['rets'])) - 1
```

If you want it lined up with your original returns, just shift it up 1 row

**EDIT:**

If you are missing the original returns and want to back into them from `cum_rets` you can use this:

```
df['rets_missing'] = (1 + df['cum_rets']) / (1 + df['cum_rets'].shift(1)) - 1
```